# Basis for monomials $x^p_1x^q_2$ using $x^s$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, change-of-basis

Let $s\in\mathbb{N}$. I have a sum of the form
$$
    \sum_{p+q\leq s}c_{p,q}x^p_1x^q_2,
$$
and want to write it in terms of functions taking the form
$$
    g(x,(c_0,c_1,c_2)) = (c_0+c_1x_1+c_2x_2)^s.
$$
I want to use as few as possible terms $g(x,(c_0,c_1,c_2))$ to describe the entire sum. To understand how to do that I first want to find one set of $g(x,(c_0,c_1,c_2))$ for each $(p,q)$, i.e. find a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
  x_1^px_2^q = \sum_{(c_0,c_1,c_2)\in S}g(x,((c_0,c_1,c_2)).
$$
For the simple cases I have

| (p,q) | S |
| --- | --- |
| (0,0) | {(1,0,0)} |
| (s,0) | {(0,1,0)} |
| (0,s) | {(0,0,1)} |

and I know that $g$ can also be written as
$$
   g(x,(c_0,c_1,c_2)) = \sum_{k_0+k_1+k_2=s}\frac{s!}{k_0!k_1!k_2!}c^{k_0}_0c^{k_1}_1c^{k_2}_2x^{k_1}_1x^{k_2}_2
$$

Is there an explicit way of writing $S$ for the other $(p,q)$?

#### -- edit --

For $s=2$ the full list is (up to multiplicative constants)

| (p,q) | S |
| --- | --- |
| (0,0) | {(1,0,0)} |
| (1,0) | {(1,1,0),(0,-1,0),(-1,0,0)} |
| (0,1) | {(1,0,1),(0,0,-1),(-1,0,0)} |
| (1,1) | {(0,0,-1),(0,-1,0),(0,1,1)} |
| (2,0) | {(0,1,0)} |
| (0,2) | {(0,0,1)} |